# Помогите построить выражения vba access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access

Помогите построить выражения (VBA).

1. Open Form, поля Pole3 и Pole4 Visible = False;
2. Из выпадающего списка Pole2 выбирая USA, нам возвращается поля в Form Footer (с желтым фонам) Pole3 и Pole4 Visible = True;

Моя версия не работает.

[test visible field.accdb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uUyGEyDQLLzD99Kklo3JxV4mEMnl87qr)

[screen open form.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xhm_p9iCsD1J7SH2xx05oZAcZRYo26mH/view?usp=sharing)

[screen vb .jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wkMMnjdDZHQK3WHViGI98QRcTTFU_8hF/view?usp=sharing)

Заранее благодарю